# Google Script for sending mass emails from Sheets stopped working. I didn't change the code

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found a script that worked for sending batch emails straight from Google Sheets. I used it occasionally and it worked great. And then it just stopped working. When I run the code below, I see the message "Execution completed", but the emails don't arrive.

I can read basic code and that's about the extent of my knowledge. That is to say, that the only things I change in what you see below are the subject of the email, the number of rows to process and the parameters in getRange.

I've tried to use the script on diffrent sheets, from different Google Accounts. No luck.

I would be greatful for your help.

Edit 1: I copied the code, made a new file and ran it there. It only sent an email to the address in row 4, even though the range was set to be from row 1 to 5. I am very confused now.

```js
  //Прежде чем запускать, убедись, что ты сидишь с того аккаунта, с которого должны улететь письма!!!
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 5;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:B5
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Script Test 18/02";
    MailApp.sendEmail( emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: if there are no emails sent, it means that `data` is empty. Do a simple check and you will be able to spot the issue. Put `console.log(data)` after `data` and go to either execution page or Log page to see the output of `data`.

Comment: As @Marios mentioned for each loops don't iterate unless there's data  inside. Please share a Spreadsheet example without sensitive data, it'd be helpful if we had the `console.log(data)` value as well.